# Can I use my xbox controller to play alien swarm?

Tags: pc, controllers, alien-swarm

I know the information page for [Alien Swarm](http://store.steampowered.com/app/630/) does not list it, but from the screenshots it seems like a perfect game to control with the xbox controller.

Did they just forget to add the icon or is it really not possible to use?

<sub>I guess I'm asking this question to somebody who has played the game</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does require you to go into the console and enable the xbox controller. I've got it working fine on my game, I just need to figure out how to customize it because currently it is not allowing me to swap weapons via controller.

As of 2015, go

1. Settings
2. Keyboard and Mouse
3. Check "Enable Developer Console"
4. Open the console by pressing <kbd>`</kbd> (backtick, same key as <kbd>~</kbd>)
5. Enter `exec 360controller_xbox` (or try `exec 360controller_pc`)
6. Go back to Keyboard and Mouse settings to view or change the keybindings

Some related info: [Using an XBox 360 Controller with Source Games](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?p_faqid=421)

Comment: [Today's update](http://store.steampowered.com/news/4104/) says "Fixed weapon switch key in the 360 controller config". Would you let us know if you can get it to work?

Comment: You can now change weapons by using the `Y` key, also, I think it autodetects if you have a controller plugged in and execs that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Simply type in console `exec 360controller_xbox.cfg` or if you're using the PC version of the gamepad, `exec 360controller_pc.cfg` to bind the joypad's buttons accordingly.

These files are located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\alien swarm\swarm\cfg\`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can, although you have to map controls yourself. Hit up this forum post:

http://forums.blackcatgames.com/showthread.php?t=11119

Comment: With that said, the Alien Swarm FAQ (http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?s=e3a21808a5b439782cb93047e5cc814a&t=1365797) says that controllers are not supported (neither are Macs)

Comment: Basically, it doesn't. Albort's answer involves mapping the controller to your keyboard and mouse, which is basically a hack that will allow you to use an Xbox controller with any game.

Comment: It looks like this thread is for the Unreal version, not the Source version.  :/

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice that either. It's for the UT04 mod.